# Вопрос по формам

Tags: javascript, html

При отправке формы человек попадает на страницу оплаты. Как сделать так, чтобы оплата происходила в новом окне?

```html
<form id="bank" name="bank" method="POST" action="https://money.site.ru/shop.xml">
```

Comment: что за эпидемия с написанием "что бы" ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский что бы Вы ни делали, найдутся люди, которые будут писать раздельно :)

Comment: @Igor если бы они в правильных местах это делали. А эта тотальная неграмотность уже начинает раздражать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, меня она просто-таки доводит до белого колена

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибут `target` тэга `form`:

```
<form target="_blank" id="bank" name="bank" ...
```

http://html.com/attributes/form-target/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form